# Nested Fragment pop back in order

Tags: android

How to create nested Fragment A -> B -> C

- A, activity
- B, fragment
- C, fragment

when i'm on fragment C, i press back button. It instantly return to A, i need it to return to B first, then A. C fragment will override B fragment view. Can someone guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking fragment as follow :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);//or use add(), choose your method wisely as per your requirement.
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);//this will add frag to backstack
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Hope it helps.